# Ruby - Get time at start of next minute

Tags: ruby, datetime

I'm looking for a concise way to get a Ruby `Time` object representing the top of the next minute (and hour/day/month/year, if possible).  I want this to work in a pure Ruby environment, so the Rails function `Time.change` or similar doesn't fit the bill.

At first this seems simple - just add 1 to `Time.now`, but there are edge cases where if, for example, you try to instantiate a `Time` object with `Time.now.min + 1` when the current minute is 59, you get an `ArgumentError: min out of range`. This goes for hour, day, and month as well.

I have some lengthy code that does the job. It's ugly, but I'm just experimenting:

```
def add_minute

    now = Time.local
    year = now.year
    month = now.month
    day = now.day
    hour = now.hour
    min = now.min

    if now.min == 59
        if now.hour == 23
            if now.day == Date.civil(now.year, now.month, -1).day
                if month == 12
                    year = year + 1
                    month = 1
                    day = 1
                    hour = 0
                    min = 0
                else
                    month = now.month + 1
                    day = 1
                    hour = 0
                    min = 0
                end
            else
                day = now.day + 1
                hour = 0
                min = 0
            end
        else
            hour = now.hour + 1
            min = 0
        end
    else
        min = now.min + 1
    end

    Time.local year, month, day, hour, min, 0
end
```

This seems absurdly verbose for what seems like it should be a simple or built-in task, but I haven't found a native Ruby solution.  Does one exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the `Time` object to UNIX epoch time (seconds since 1970) using `#to_i`, add 60 s, and then convert back to a `Time` object.

```
time_unix = Time.now.to_i
time_unix_one_min_later = time_unix + 60
time_one_min_later = t = Time.at(time_unix_one_min_later)
time_one_min_later_rounded_down = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min)
```

EDIT: Even shorter - you can just add integer seconds to `Time.now` directly:

```
time_one_min_later = t = Time.now + 60
time_one_min_later_rounded_down = Time.new(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.min)
```

EDIT 2: One-liner - just subtract `Time.now.sec`:

```
time_one_min_later_rounded_down = Time.now + 60 - Time.now.sec
```

Comment: I'm a little embarrassed I didn't think of this. Sometimes I get so caught up in what the class's methods are capable of, I forget to consider the underlying mechanics the class is built on.

Comment: No worries. Here's an even more concise solution `time_one_min_later_rounded_down = Time.now + 60 - Time.now.sec`

Answer (score 2):

Other option, given one second to midnight:

```
require 'time'
now = Time.strptime('2018-12-31 23:59:59', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Within one minute:

```
Time.at(now + 60) #=> 2019-01-01 00:00:59 +0100
Time.at(now + 60 - now.sec) #=> 2019-01-01 00:00:00 +0100
```

You get: **`# HAPPY NEW YEAR!`**

Comment: Clever solution with subtracting `now.sec`!

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has built in methods for adding months (`>>`) and days (`+`). A year is 12 months, and an hour is 1/24th of a day.

```
require 'date'

def add_time(time, year: 0 ,month: 0, day: 0, hour: 0, minute: 0)
  time >>= 12*year
  time >>= month
  time +=  day
  time +=  Rational(hour,24)       # or (hour/24.0) if you dislike rationals
  time +=  Rational(minute, 24*60) # (minute/24.0*60) if you dislike rationals
end

p t = DateTime.now
p add_time(t, year: 1, minute: 30)
```

Comment: This is a good answer to the question in general, but my use case (as presented in the question) is specific to a `Time` object, whereas these methods require a `DateTime` object.  Still, it's good info, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not that clean without ActiveSupport:

```
new_date = (DateTime.now + 1.to_f / (60*24))
DateTime.new(new_date.year, new_date.month, new_date.day, new_date.hour, new_date.minute)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make this calculation easier to understand by getting the current number of seconds we are through the day. (optional)

`DateTime.current.to_i` gives us the number of seconds since 1970
`DateTime.current.to_i - DateTime.current.beginning_of_day.to_i` gives us the number of seconds since the start of the day.

`(((number_of_seconds_through_the_day + 60)/60) * 60)` gives us the number of seconds we will be at when the next minute starts

Then we subtract the two to give us the number of seconds until the top of the next minute.

If we want the exact time at start of the next minute then we can do:

`DateTime.current + seconds_until_start_of_the_next_minute.seconds`

```
def seconds_until_start_of_the_next_minute
  number_of_seconds_through_the_day = DateTime.current.to_i - DateTime.current.beginning_of_day.to_i
  number_of_seconds_through_the_day_at_next_minute = (((number_of_seconds_through_the_day + 60)/60) * 60)
  seconds_until_next_minute_starts = number_of_seconds_through_the_day_at_next_minute - number_of_seconds_through_the_day
  return seconds_until_next_minute_starts
end
```